# Can not call requestLocationUpdates with given arguments

Tags: android, geolocation

```
private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null

/*onCreate()*/
locationManager = requireActivity()
        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

/*Listener is declared as */
private val locationListener = LocationListener {
     ...
}

 /*Then on button click I want to request location update and hope to see update in my listener*/
 locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(
        "dsa",
        0.toLong(),
        0.toFloat(),
        locationListener!!
    )
```

I want to test `requestLocationUpdates`, but it says that functions does not support given arguments. Weird, because there's `requestLocationUpdates` with String, Long, Float, LocationListener attributes. What could cause this? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get more than one error with your code. The reason is that `LocationListener` is an `interface` and you are treating it as something else. To fix this, change the LocationListener code to the following snippet.

`public val locationListener = object: LocationListener{
...
}`

Remember to override all the necessary methods.Also remove the Non null assertion `!!`, there's no need for that. The error should go away now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

**An `IllegalArgumentException` will throw if provider is null or doesn't exist on this device.**
I think the "**dsa**" provider may not exist in your device. You should use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`, `LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER`, or `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`